# Java and LibGdx - Fatal error during run-time

Tags: java, android

I am working on a game using LibGdx and Java. While I play the game, sometimes I get this run-time error that I never saw before and I have no idea what it means.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000066bcbd0d, pid=3632, tid=0x000000000000220c
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_76-b03) (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.76-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0xbd0d]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\MarioBros\android\assets\hs_err_pid3632.log AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

The error log is below:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000066bcbd0d, pid=3632, tid=0x000000000000220c
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_76-b03) (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.76-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0xbd0d]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000017d41000):  JavaThread "LWJGL Application" [_thread_in_native, id=8716, stack(0x00000000188d0000,0x00000000189d0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000002059d0bef0

Registers:
RAX=0x0000002059d0bef0, RBX=0x0000000059cc6f50, RCX=0x0000000059cc6f20, RDX=0x00000000000000b8
RSP=0x00000000189ced90, RBP=0x0000000000000006, RSI=0x0000000059cc6f20, RDI=0x00000000189cee50
R8 =0x0000000059cc6f20, R9 =0x0000000000000002, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000001
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000000156f6d58, R14=0x00000000189cf038, R15=0x0000000017d41000
RIP=0x0000000066bcbd0d, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000000189ced90)
0x00000000189ced90:   00000000156f6d58 0000000017d41000
0x00000000189ceda0:   000000005f2a6628 0000000017f2dff0
0x00000000189cedb0:   0000000000000012 0000000059cc6f20
0x00000000189cedc0:   0000000014f60480 00000000189cee50
0x00000000189cedd0:   00000000189cef90 0000000000000000
0x00000000189cede0:   00000000156f6d58 0000000066be2483
0x00000000189cedf0:   00000000189cee90 00000000189cee90
0x00000000189cee00:   0000000000000003 00000000156f6d58
0x00000000189cee10:   0000000000000001 0000000014f60480
0x00000000189cee20:   000000000006e998 0000000066be8616
0x00000000189cee30:   0000000000000000 000000000006e998
0x00000000189cee40:   00000000189cef90 00000000033054d8
0x00000000189cee50:   4189999a00000002 000000003f6147ae
0x00000000189cee60:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000000189cee70:   0000010100000000 00000000189cf001
0x00000000189cee80:   0000000000000000 000000003f800000 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000066bcbd0d)
0x0000000066bcbced:   48 8d 05 6c a3 05 00 0f b6 1c 18 80 fb 0d 0f b6
0x0000000066bcbcfd:   eb 77 21 48 8d 1c de 48 8b 43 10 48 85 c0 74 3a
0x0000000066bcbd0d:   48 8b 10 48 89 53 10 48 83 c4 28 5b 5e 5f 5d 41
0x0000000066bcbd1d:   5c 41 5d c3 48 8d 15 18 9e 04 00 48 8d 0d 99 9e 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000002059d0bef0 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000059cc6f50 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000059cc6f20 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00000000000000b8 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00000000189ced90 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000017d41000
RBP=0x0000000000000006 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000059cc6f20 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000189cee50 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000017d41000
R8 =0x0000000059cc6f20 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x00000000156f6d60} 'jniCreateBody' '(JIFFFFFFFFZZZZZF)J' in 'com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World'
R14=0x00000000189cf038 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000017d41000
R15=0x0000000017d41000 is a thread


Stack: [0x00000000188d0000,0x00000000189d0000],  sp=0x00000000189ced90,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0xbd0d]
C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0x22483]
C  [gdx-box2d64.dll+0x28616]
C  0x0000000003315b74

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniCreateBody(JIFFFFFFFFZZZZZF)J+0
j  com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.createBody(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/BodyDef;)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body;+80
j  com.kanzuu.mariobros.sprites.Mushroom.defineItem()V+37
J 1366 C2 com.kanzuu.mariobros.screens.PlayScreen.render(F)V (216 bytes) @ 0x000000000388a0a8 [0x0000000003887220+0x2e88]
J 1231 C1 com.kanzuu.mariobros.MarioBros.render()V (5 bytes) @ 0x00000000037ae75c [0x00000000037ae5a0+0x1bc]
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop()V+698
j  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run()V+27
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000000181e2800 JavaThread "LWJGL Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3932, stack(0x0000000061d60000,0x0000000061e60000)]
  0x0000000017f2a000 JavaThread "AsynchExecutor-Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10532, stack(0x000000005e990000,0x000000005ea90000)]
  0x0000000003202800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=3260, stack(0x0000000003100000,0x0000000003200000)]
=>0x0000000017d41000 JavaThread "LWJGL Application" [_thread_in_native, id=8716, stack(0x00000000188d0000,0x00000000189d0000)]
  0x0000000017407800 JavaThread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6948, stack(0x0000000017870000,0x0000000017970000)]
  0x0000000017290800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8500, stack(0x0000000017670000,0x0000000017770000)]
  0x0000000015928000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10796, stack(0x0000000017170000,0x0000000017270000)]
  0x0000000015904800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3828, stack(0x0000000017070000,0x0000000017170000)]
  0x00000000158fe000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6468, stack(0x0000000016f70000,0x0000000017070000)]
  0x00000000158fd000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8916, stack(0x0000000016e70000,0x0000000016f70000)]
  0x00000000158fc000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9308, stack(0x0000000016d70000,0x0000000016e70000)]
  0x00000000032fe000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6688, stack(0x0000000016b70000,0x0000000016c70000)]
  0x00000000032f3800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10324, stack(0x0000000016a70000,0x0000000016b70000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00000000158c5000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000016970000,0x0000000016a70000] [id=6676]
  0x000000001595e000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000017770000,0x0000000017870000] [id=7068]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 11735K [0x00000000eb200000, 0x00000000ec700000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 16384K, 56% used [0x00000000eb200000,0x00000000ebaf85a8,0x00000000ec200000)
  from space 2560K, 99% used [0x00000000ec200000,0x00000000ec47d9d0,0x00000000ec480000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ec480000,0x00000000ec480000,0x00000000ec700000)
 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 1421K [0x00000000c1600000, 0x00000000c4100000, 0x00000000eb200000)
  object space 44032K, 3% used [0x00000000c1600000,0x00000000c1763538,0x00000000c4100000)
 Metaspace       used 9323K, capacity 9471K, committed 9600K, reserved 1058816K
  class space    used 855K, capacity 884K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x00000000126c0000,0x00000000128c0000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000120b5000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000005f469d00
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012e10000, 0x0000000013db8000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000013db8000, 0x0000000014d60000)

Polling page: 0x0000000001370000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=5867Kb max_used=5878Kb free=239892Kb
 bounds [0x0000000003300000, 0x00000000038d0000, 0x0000000012300000]
 total_blobs=1969 nmethods=1462 adapters=421
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 81.235 Thread 0x0000000015928000 1458       3       org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard$KeyEvent::access$602 (7 bytes)
Event: 81.236 Thread 0x0000000015928000 nmethod 1458 0x00000000038b9f10 code [0x00000000038ba060, 0x00000000038ba190]
Event: 81.236 Thread 0x0000000015928000 1459       3       org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard$KeyEvent::access$202 (7 bytes)
Event: 81.236 Thread 0x0000000015928000 nmethod 1459 0x00000000038ba250 code [0x00000000038ba3a0, 0x00000000038ba4f0]
Event: 81.683 Thread 0x0000000015904800 1460       4       java.nio.DirectByteBuffer::put (126 bytes)
Event: 81.690 Thread 0x0000000015904800 nmethod 1460 0x00000000038bd3d0 code [0x00000000038bd520, 0x00000000038bd778]
Event: 83.421 Thread 0x0000000015928000 1461       3       com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.GlyphLayout::setText (1035 bytes)
Event: 83.432 Thread 0x0000000015928000 nmethod 1461 0x00000000038bda10 code [0x00000000038bdea0, 0x00000000038c1098]
Event: 85.203 Thread 0x00000000158fe000 1462       4       org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsKeyboard::flushRetained (37 bytes)
Event: 85.208 Thread 0x00000000158fe000 nmethod 1462 0x00000000038c3790 code [0x00000000038c3900, 0x00000000038c3ac8]

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 2.161 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 16384K [0x00000000eb200000, 0x00000000ec700000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 16384K, 100% used [0x00000000eb200000,0x00000000ec200000,0x00000000ec200000)
  from space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ec480000,0x00000000ec480000,0x00000000ec700000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ec200000,0x00000000ec200000,0x00000000ec480000)
 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 0K [0x00000000c1600000, 0x00000000c4100000, 0x00000000eb200000)
  object space 44032K, 0% used [0x00000000c1600000,0x00000000c1600000,0x00000000c4100000)
 Metaspace       used 7337K, capacity 7491K, committed 7680K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 683K, capacity 720K, committed 768K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2.165 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 18944K, used 2550K [0x00000000eb200000, 0x00000000ec700000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 16384K, 0% used [0x00000000eb200000,0x00000000eb200000,0x00000000ec200000)
  from space 2560K, 99% used [0x00000000ec200000,0x00000000ec47d9d0,0x00000000ec480000)
  to   space 2560K, 0% used [0x00000000ec480000,0x00000000ec480000,0x00000000ec700000)
 ParOldGen       total 44032K, used 1421K [0x00000000c1600000, 0x00000000c4100000, 0x00000000eb200000)
  object space 44032K, 3% used [0x00000000c1600000,0x00000000c1763538,0x00000000c4100000)
 Metaspace       used 7337K, capacity 7491K, committed 7680K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 683K, capacity 720K, committed 768K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 14.201 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000036ba918 method=com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array$ArrayIterable.iterator()Ljava/util/Iterator; @ 4
Event: 14.201 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000036c40d4 method=com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture.getShape()Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Shape; @ 4
Event: 14.750 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000036d9084 method=com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer.getColorByBody(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body;)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Color; @ 46
Event: 14.767 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000036d3670 method=com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer.getColorByBody(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body;)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Color; @ 46
Event: 15.902 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003710c3c method=com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer.renderTileLayer(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TiledMapTileLayer;)V @ 243
Event: 16.222 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003758528 method=com.jcraft.jorbis.Floor1.inverse1(Lcom/jcraft/jorbis/Block;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 31
Event: 16.222 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003659c34 method=com.jcraft.jorbis.Mapping0.inverse(Lcom/jcraft/jorbis/Block;Ljava/lang/Object;)I @ 214
Event: 33.413 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003810fcc method=com.kanzuu.mariobros.sprites.Goomba.update(F)V @ 14
Event: 33.414 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000037ef298 method=com.kanzuu.mariobros.sprites.Goomba.draw(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch;)V @ 4
Event: 61.620 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000037abf6c method=com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer.getColorByBody(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body;)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Color; @ 46

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 1.615 Thread 0x0000000003202800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb68d258) thrown at [C:\src\android\AOSP-openjdk\external\jetbrains\jdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 1.615 Thread 0x0000000003202800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb68ef30) thrown at [C:\src\android\AOSP-openjdk\external\jetbrains\jdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 1.615 Thread 0x0000000003202800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb6900a0) thrown at [C:\src\android\AOSP-openjdk\external\jetbrains\jdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 1.616 Thread 0x0000000003202800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb695208) thrown at [C:\src\android\AOSP-openjdk\external\jetbrains\jdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 1.616 Thread 0x0000000003202800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb695e60) thrown at [C:\src\android\AOSP-openjdk\external\jetbrains\jdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 1.616 Thread 0x0000000003202800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000eb696a88) thrown at [C:\src\android\AOSP-openjdk\external\jetbrains\jdk\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 14.201 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000037d0f5d to 0x00000000037d5a8d
Event: 14.201 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000036ba8b0 to 0x00000000036ba905
Event: 14.201 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Implicit null exception at 0x00000000036c17c0 to 0x00000000036c40c9
Event: 15.902 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Implicit null exception at 0x000000000370f34e to 0x0000000003710bd1

Events (10 events):
Event: 21.588 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x00000000033475bf sp=0x00000000189cec48 mode 0
Event: 33.413 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x0000000003810fcc
Event: 33.413 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000003810fcc sp=0x00000000189cef10
Event: 33.413 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000000000334556a sp=0x00000000189ceee8 mode 2
Event: 33.414 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x00000000037ef298
Event: 33.414 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00000000037ef298 sp=0x00000000189ceff0
Event: 33.414 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000000000334556a sp=0x00000000189cefc8 mode 2
Event: 61.620 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x00000000037abf6c
Event: 61.620 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x00000000037abf6c sp=0x00000000189cef70
Event: 61.620 Thread 0x0000000017d41000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000000000334556a sp=0x00000000189ceeb0 mode 2


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff6d2b10000 - 0x00007ff6d2b41000     C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe
0x00007ffcdc740000 - 0x00007ffcdc911000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffcdc3c0000 - 0x00007ffcdc46b000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffcd8f00000 - 0x00007ffcd911d000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffcdc480000 - 0x00007ffcdc522000     C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffcdc6a0000 - 0x00007ffcdc73e000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffcdbd50000 - 0x00007ffcdbda9000     C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffcda000000 - 0x00007ffcda121000     C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffcdbf30000 - 0x00007ffcdc095000     C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffcd8ee0000 - 0x00007ffcd8efe000     C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffcdb8e0000 - 0x00007ffcdb914000     C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffcd92f0000 - 0x00007ffcd9472000     C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ffcc9d20000 - 0x00007ffcc9f99000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.14393.447_none_42191651c6827bb3\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ffcd9cd0000 - 0x00007ffcd9f98000     C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ffcd8de0000 - 0x00007ffcd8ed5000     C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ffcd9530000 - 0x00007ffcd959a000     C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffcda130000 - 0x00007ffcda15e000     C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x000000005eaf0000 - 0x000000005ebc2000     C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000005ecb0000 - 0x000000005f4e4000     C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffcdc530000 - 0x00007ffcdc538000     C:\Windows\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffcd0f60000 - 0x00007ffcd0f6a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffcd6cf0000 - 0x00007ffcd6d13000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffcbc990000 - 0x00007ffcbc999000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x0000000001870000 - 0x000000000189b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffcdc350000 - 0x00007ffcdc3ba000     C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffcd95a0000 - 0x00007ffcd95e2000     C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ffcd5220000 - 0x00007ffcd522f000     C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x00007ffcd2c20000 - 0x00007ffcd2c49000     C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\java.dll
0x00007ffcd3d90000 - 0x00007ffcd3da6000     C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ffcda2a0000 - 0x00007ffcdb7a9000     C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffcd95f0000 - 0x00007ffcd9cca000     C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ffcd8bc0000 - 0x00007ffcd8c0c000     C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ffcd9fa0000 - 0x00007ffcd9ff2000     C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ffcd8c20000 - 0x00007ffcd8c2f000     C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffcd8c90000 - 0x00007ffcd8d39000     C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ffcd8ba0000 - 0x00007ffcd8bb4000     C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffcd5290000 - 0x00007ffcd529f000     C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\breakgen64.dll
0x00007ffcd2c00000 - 0x00007ffcd2c1a000     C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007ffcd83a0000 - 0x00007ffcd83fc000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x0000000065580000 - 0x0000000065616000     C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxDaniel\a9daadd6\gdx64.dll
0x00007ffcd8670000 - 0x00007ffcd8687000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x00007ffcd8580000 - 0x00007ffcd85b3000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x00007ffcd8ae0000 - 0x00007ffcd8b0b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x00007ffcd8220000 - 0x00007ffcd823f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ffcd8690000 - 0x00007ffcd869b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x00007ffcd8130000 - 0x00007ffcd8168000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x00007ffcdb7b0000 - 0x00007ffcdb7b8000     C:\Windows\System32\NSI.dll
0x00007ffcd2580000 - 0x00007ffcd2596000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x00007ffcd26c0000 - 0x00007ffcd26da000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x00007ffcd2be0000 - 0x00007ffcd2bf1000     C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000180000000 - 0x0000000180053000     C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxDaniel\dc0f0009\lwjgl64.dll
0x00007ffcc43d0000 - 0x00007ffcc44f3000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.dll
0x00007ffcc0b40000 - 0x00007ffcc0c37000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DDRAW.dll
0x00007ffcca5d0000 - 0x00007ffcca5fd000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll
0x00007ffcd2c60000 - 0x00007ffcd2c68000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x00000000184b0000 - 0x0000000018514000     C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxDaniel\dc0f0009\OpenAL64.dll
0x00007ffcda160000 - 0x00007ffcda297000     C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
0x00007ffcd7310000 - 0x00007ffcd73a5000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007ffcc1260000 - 0x00007ffcc12f8000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tiptsf.dll
0x00007ffcdb820000 - 0x00007ffcdb8df000     C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007ffcd8d40000 - 0x00007ffcd8ddc000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ffcdc2b0000 - 0x00007ffcdc34f000     C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll
0x00007ffcd69e0000 - 0x00007ffcd6b65000     C:\Windows\System32\PROPSYS.dll
0x00007ffcc7920000 - 0x00007ffcc79bb000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dsound.dll
0x00007ffcd1ec0000 - 0x00007ffcd1f31000     C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll
0x00007ffcd7850000 - 0x00007ffcd7878000     C:\Windows\System32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00007ffcb7e30000 - 0x00007ffcb7ec4000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\AUDIOSES.DLL
0x00007ffcd57a0000 - 0x00007ffcd58d6000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
0x00007ffcdbdd0000 - 0x00007ffcdbf2b000     C:\Windows\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ffcd69b0000 - 0x00007ffcd69d6000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x00007ffcabe70000 - 0x00007ffcac98f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ig75icd64.dll
0x00007ffcd6890000 - 0x00007ffcd68a3000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x00007ffcd3310000 - 0x00007ffcd3d2f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\igdusc64.dll
0x00007ffcc7fc0000 - 0x00007ffcc8051000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mscms.dll
0x00007ffcca040000 - 0x00007ffcca082000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\icm32.dll
0x00007ffcc13b0000 - 0x00007ffcc155a000     C:\Windows\System32\uiautomationcore.dll
0x00007ffcd8a40000 - 0x00007ffcd8ad8000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sxs.dll
0x00007ffcc0c60000 - 0x00007ffcc0cc5000     C:\Windows\System32\OLEACC.dll
0x0000000066bc0000 - 0x0000000066c7b000     C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\libgdxDaniel\6812b6ed\gdx-box2d64.dll
0x00007ffcd0340000 - 0x00007ffcd04d2000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Didea.launcher.port=7534 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.kanzuu.mariobros.desktop.DesktopLauncher
java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\MarioBros\desktop\build\classes\main;C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\MarioBros\core\build\classes\main;C:\Users\Daniel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx\1.9.5\dc65bb2f51828c58b1b2b3ac585357204d54ee5f\gdx-1.9.5.jar;C:\Users\Daniel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-box2d\1.9.5\c8098219abfe00b849cc43d461b1105fea3a2944\gdx-box2d-1.9.5.jar;C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\MarioBros\core\build\libs\core-1.0.jar;C:\Users\Daniel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-backend-lwjgl\1.9.5\ad5223b755809a92f44e7f6208f4af6a3b39dcc0\gdx-backend-lwjgl-1.9.5.jar;C:\Users\Daniel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.badlogicgames.gdx\gdx-platform\1.9.5\bc0c7ee7fca96eb3c691b5a87cf11fd4d9f1bab6\gdx-platform-1.9.5-natives-desktop.jar;C:\Users\Dan
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
USERNAME=Daniel
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 14393 (10.0.14393.0)

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 69 stepping 1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2

Memory: 4k page, physical 4097096k(1230988k free), swap 11769208k(5116492k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.76-b03) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_76-release-b03), built on Jun 29 2016 19:09:20 by "ralucas" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Sun Dec 25 01:54:43 2016
elapsed time: 86 seconds (0d 0h 1m 26s)
```

**EDIT:** I was able to find out that the application crashes (only sometimes) in the function below:

```
@Override
    public void defineItem() {
        System.out.println("mushroom going to be created");
        BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
        System.out.println("1");
        bdef.position.set(getX(), getY());
        System.out.println("2");
        bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody; 
        System.out.println("3");
        _body = _world.createBody(bdef); //The application crashes here...
        System.out.println("4");
        FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
        CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
        circle.setRadius(6 / MarioBros.PPM);

        fdef.filter.categoryBits = MarioBros.ENEMY_BIT;
        fdef.filter.maskBits = MarioBros.GROUND_BIT |
                MarioBros.COIN_BIT |
                MarioBros.BRICK_BIT |
                MarioBros.ENEMY_BIT |
                MarioBros.OBJECT_BIT |
                MarioBros.MARIO_BIT;

        fdef.shape = circle;
        _body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData(this);
        System.out.println("mushroom added");
    }
```

Can someone give me some help? 
Please let me know if I need to show any more details or code from my application.

Thank you and merry Christmas!

Comment: I also would like to say that it looks some kind of segmentation fault, but I don´t even know how it is possible in java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some debugging and some talking with other friend we found out the problem was that I was removing a Body from the World (both Box2D classes) and after that I was calling a method on that body (the method was setActive(true)).

The solution was to set the Body to **null** after he destruction, this allowed me to get a NullPointerException when if I tried to use that body after his destruction and finally find the bug on the application.

**In conclusion:** If you use Box2D always set a Body to null after it gets destroyed in the World.

Comment: I'm getting the same error using almost identical code. I've tried setting the body to null but I'm not getting an exception. Have you got any more info on this? I'm really struggling.

Comment: In my case I just set the body to null IN EVERY SINGLE ENTITY of my game and It worked. Maybe the problem in  your application is other?

Comment: FOUND IT !!!!  You were right, the issue seemed to be with one of the other entities, not the one I thought most likely or the one most recently added. Thank you. Hours of frustration - resolved.